# The value provided for the report parameter '' is not valid for its type. (rsReportParameterTypeMismatch)

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2014

I am working on SSRS Report.

Continuously getting bellow error does anyone have idea to sovle?

> The value provided for the report parameter '' is not valid for its
>   type. (rsReportParameterTypeMismatch)

Using query something like below - My query type is **Text**

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
    ....
) 

INSERT INTO #Temp
  (
   ...
  )
SELECT ...
FROM   ... joins TABLE....
WHERE  d.Date BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate

SELECT ...
FROM   #Temp 
.. joins TABLE...
WHERE ...

DROP TABLE #Temp
```

Image that shows the error.

[image]

Comment: Aren't you typing the date on the textbox? Use the datepicker. Also check the `Date` column type in your database.

Comment: Since you're typing in `@ToDate` in `dd-mm-yy` format, check under Report properties that Language is set to whatever you need it to be (default for en-us is `mm/dd/yyy`).

Comment: what's the format of your `date` in your `Database`

Answer (score 0):

Probably incorrect Date format on the server.
To resolve it, change the Date format on the host to en-us via Control Panel